# GParted partition resize using a broken USB flash drive failed halfway through

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I have a Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot on same drive (500GB WD blue) and Ubuntu partition's size was 46GB and it got full so I thought of taking some space from the Windows 10 partition like 15GB. I googled how to take space from Windows to extend the Ubuntu partition, and I found out about GParted partition editor.

I watched this [YouTube video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=yOOcg5Cm4DM). What this guy in video does is that he shrank a Windows partition and brought that partition adjacent to the Linux (Ubuntu) partition.

Then it booted into Linux live CD, opened GParted, and resized the Linux partition and it got resized.

Now I did the same thing... shrank the Windows 10 partition and that partition is adjacent to the Ubuntu partition.

Now I had a SanDisk USB flash drive (Ubuntu live USB) which is this one:

[image]

As you can see the top of the USB flash drive is broken off, but I plugged it in to the laptop's USB port anyway. It can't be plugged in firmly. If I touch the USB flash drive a little bit it gets disconnected. I booted the Linux live CD and opened GParted and tried to resize the partition with it.

GParted copied 11GB out of 61GB, then accidentally my hand touched the USB flash drive and it got disconnected, and GParted got stuck because USB disconnect = Ubuntu live USB disconnect.

Then I restarted my laptop and now I used a good USB flash drive (a new one) and opened GParted again and I saw a red (!) icon beside my Ubuntu partition `/dev/sda6`. I right-clicked on it and checked it.

GParted showed this screen:

[image]

I'm asking if there any fix, I mean like completing the GParted copying? GParted is a great tool, but I'm dumb and used a broken USB flash drive to try to resize the Ubuntu partition from 46GB to 61GB.

Comment: It's corrupt. Delete Ubuntu partitions and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't trust the results of a partition resize operation that was done with a USB flash drive that could not be inserted firmly into the USB port. That model of USB flash drive costs less than $5 USD for the 16GB model, and you should have thrown it out as soon as you saw that it was broken.

The laptop's Ubuntu partition is corrupted, and it's possible that some data on the Ubuntu partition has been lost. GParted didn't do anything to change the Windows 10 partition, so the files on the Windows 10 partition are still OK. Your best course of action to avoid descending into chaos is to backup your personal files on the laptop's Ubuntu partition from another bootable Ubuntu live USB flash drive, delete the Ubuntu partition with a bootable Ubuntu/GParted live USB (but don't delete the Windows 10 partition(s)), and reinstall Ubuntu.